# how to add a numeric spinner

Tags: javascript, html

so im trying to make a collection tracker for my magic cards because i dont currently like any of them out there and i have somewhere close to 15,000 cards and its really hard to keep track of that in my head :P. so what i did was i found this guide 
http://dataforradicals.com/the-absurdly-illustrated-guide-to-sortable-searchable-online-data-tables/#comment-209
and it was extremely helpful but there are 3 parts that i would like to try to add to this. i would like to add a numeric spinner to each card so all i have to do is search on the webpage and +1 or -1 to whatever card i bought or sold. i would also like to add the low med high prices that can be found on tcgplayer.com. and lastly i would like to add either a picture when i hover over the name or the little camera button that they have on their site would work out well also. http://store.tcgplayer.com/collection/view/66999

please let me if you have any suggestions and thank you for taking the time to help me out :)

Answer (score 0):

You have three questions in one, but I'll answer the primary (title) question.

So the easiest, crudest way to do this is to use `<input type="number">`. In *most* modern browsers, this will produce UI that will give you the functionality you're looking for. Since this project is just for you, just use a browser that produces the nice UI (basically most things but IE I believe).

If that doesn't suffice, you can turn to any number of polyfills, most notably [jQuery UI](https://jqueryui.com/spinner/).

Hope that helps!

Comment: will that work for how i have it set up? i have it set to pull the information from a google spreadsheet. if it does work, where do i add it? and the reason that i want it like this instead of keeping it in the google spreadsheet is because after i get around 10,000 cards in the spreadsheet it lags like crazy. and i feel this looks nicer set up this way. if you have any questions about how its written, i have set up exactly like the guide i mentioned above.